# I want to make this code specific to only one role, how can I do it?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
with open('database.txt') as file:
    file = file.read().split()

@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
    for database in file:
        if database in message.content.lower():
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}**! Daha hızlı banlanması için <@854087258990444564> Botuna DM At** !')
```

I want to make this code specific to only one role, how can I do it?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. What "role" are you referring to? The code snippet just reads in a text file and never mentions it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to check if the author has the role and only then execute the command.

```py
@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
    role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name='role_name')
    if role in message.author.roles:
       # command here
```

This is the simplest way I can think of, for doing this. However I highly suggest using the discord.commands framework for making bots.

### References:

- [Guild.roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20roles#discord.Guild.roles)
- [utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=utils%20get#discord.utils.get)
- [member.roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20roles#discord.Member.roles)